# How can I use JSON file in html?

Tags: javascript, html, json

The link is this: https://covid.ourworldindata.org/data/owid-covid-data.json
I want to use the data, for example, to calculate the sum of total number of cases.
The sum of the cases is then place in the html document.
However in the file it shows a lot of case with different dates. I just want the most updated case(the last case).
How can I do that?

Comment: Hello, Please give more explanasion. Are you looking for a specific date? the current date? Or maybe sum multiple dates?

Comment: In the JSON file it includes different area in the world. For example it shows one of the info which is USA, it list out all the number of case of people who get COVID-19, number of deaths and other things. The information is listed with many dates, like: on {2020-01-01 the number of cases are 100}, til today: {2021-01-30 number of cases:200} (just example). I want to extract one of the data (such as the total number of infected case) from each area, and make a sum of it. After that, I want to use it back to html.

Answer (score -1):

#### Edit

> I want to extract one of the data (such as the total number of infected case) from each area, and make a sum of it

From your comment. Can't help with the HTML part, but I can with the logical part.

```js
let sum = 0;
Object.keys(data).forEach((key) => (sum += data[key].data[0].total_cases))
console.log(sum)
```

#### Original

I didn't quite understand what you're trying to achieve. I built a small algorithm that simplifies big JSON data, and here's the output for your data collection. I hope it'll help you manipulate it. I'll edit my answer as you clarify what data you need to extract.

```json
{
  "AFG": {
    "continent": "Asia",
    "location": "Afghanistan",
    "population": 38928341,
    "population_density": 54.422,
    "median_age": 18.6,
    "aged_65_older": 2.581,
    "aged_70_older": 1.337,
    "gdp_per_capita": 1803.987,
    "cardiovasc_death_rate": 597.029,
    "diabetes_prevalence": 9.59,
    "handwashing_facilities": 37.746,
    "hospital_beds_per_thousand": 0.5,
    "life_expectancy": 64.83,
    "human_development_index": 0.498,
    "data": [
      {
        "date": "2020-02-24",
        "total_cases": 1,
        "new_cases": 1,
        "total_cases_per_million": 0.026,
        "new_cases_per_million": 0.026,
        "stringency_index": 8.33
      }
    ]
  }
}
```